# Change mouse pointer to 'hand' when hovering over a button of a screen in kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

How can I change the mouse pointer to 'hand' when hovering over a button present in a screen along with a different widget in kivy python?

I tried creating two functions in a python file. But it changes the mouse cursor for the entire page. How can I change the cursor for just the button present on the page?

```
#Kivy design file
<Loginpage>: 
name: "login"
Image:
    source: 'background.jpg'
    allow_stretch: True
    keep_ratio: False
Screen:
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None,None
        size: 400, 550
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'
    
        MDLabel:
            id: welcome_label
            text: "Welcome"
            font_size: 40
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y:15
            font_style: 'H2'

        MDTextField:
            id: uid
            hint_text: "Username"
            icon_right: "account"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

        MDTextField:
            id: pwd
            hint_text: "Password"
            icon_right: "lock"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 200
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            password: True

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "LOG IN"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_press: root.logger()

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "CLEAR"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5} 
            on_press: root.clear()  

        MDLabel:
            id: login_label
            text: "Invalid Login"
            font_size: 14
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            padding_y:15
            theme_text_color:'Custom'
            text_color: 1,0,0,1

        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 10
```

Python File:
class Loginpage(Screen):
def enter(self, *args):
Window.set_system_cursor('hand')

```
class Loginpage(Screen): 
      def enter(self, *args): 
          Window.set_system_cursor('hand')
      def leave(self, *args):
          Window.set_system_cursor('arrow')

      def logger(self):
          '''code to login'''
```

Comment: You can use method [`collide_point`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.collide_point) along with on_touch_events.

Comment: You can also bind to the `on_motion` event of `kivy.core.window.WindowBase` to get notifications of mouse position. Using that info you can use `collide_point` to determine if the mouse position is over your `Button`.